# How to wrap multiple projected content with angular 6?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to project some content into a list, i.e. add a wrapper around each projected item.

In a custom component, I have this markup:

```
<my-component>
    <a [routerLink]="path" class="link">Link1</a>
    <span class="link" someDirective>Link2</span>
    <a href="http://www.example.com>Link 3></a>
</my-component>
```

And in the `my-component` template, I would like to have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngSelectFor=".link"><ng-content></ng-content></li>
</ul>
```

The goal being to generate this markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="path" class="link">Link1</a></li>
    <li><span class="link" someDirective >Link1</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com>Link 3></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it at all possible?

Comment: Can you explain me what you really want to achieve? To do the above you just create one component with <li> links and supply data to that component using @Input.

Comment: Why don't you use your component input like this `@Input() links: string[];`? Then your template could be `<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let link of links">{{link}}</li>
  </ul>`

Comment: Because the projected elements aren't necessarly similar. I've extended my example to better show what I try to achieve.